# Project nested document to root level without using $project

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using the aggregate pipeline, I am trying to project an embedded document to the root level WITHOUT projecting each field individually and without replacing root level.

For example, I want to project this collection to the root level:

```
[
    {
        _id: "1",
        city: "NY"
        user: [ {
            firstName: "John",
            lastname: "Peters",
            brothers: [
                { _id: "B1",
                  brotherFirstName: "Karl" }
            ]
         }, {
            firstName: "Raul",
            lastname: "Other",
            brothers: [
                { _id: "B2",
                  brotherFirstName: "May" }
            ]
         }, {
            firstName: "Paul",
            lastname: "Ray",
            brothers: [
                { _id: "B3",
                  brotherFirstName: "Bryan" }
            ]
         }        
    },
    {
        _id: "2",
        city: "NY"
        user: [ {
            firstName: "Joe",
            lastname: "Anders",
            brothers: [
                { _id: "B4",
                  brotherFirstName: "Carla" }
            ]
         }, {
            firstName: "Zoy",
            lastname: "Bat",
            brothers: [
                { _id: "B5",
                  brotherFirstName: "Stuart" }
            ]
         }, {
            firstName: "Ana",
            lastname: "Lily",
            brothers: [
                { _id: "B6",
                  brotherFirstName: "Carter" }
            ]
         }        
    }
]
```

This is what I am looking for: for each document in subdocument array I want to project it to root level, so for each "user" I want to project it to "new document" and for each "brother" I want to project it to "new document"

```
[{
  _id: "1",
  city: "NY"
  firstName: "John",
  lastname: "Peters",
  brotherFirstName: "Karl" 
}, { 
  _id: "1",
  city: "NY"
  firstName: "Raul",
  lastname: "Other",
  brotherFirstName: "May" 
}, {
  _id: "1",
  city: "NY"
  firstName: "Paul",
  lastname: "Ray",
  brotherFirstName: "Bryan" 
}, {
  _id: "2",
  city: "NY"
  firstName: "Joe",
  lastname: "Anders",
  brotherFirstName: "Carla"
 }, {
  _id: "2",
  city: "NY"
  firstName: "Zoy",
  lastname: "Bat",
  brotherFirstName: "Stuart"
 }, {
  _id: "2",
  city: "NY"
  firstName: "Ana",
  lastname: "Lily",
  brotherFirstName: "Carter"
 }        
]
```

I tried aggregate $unwind e $replaceRoot, but I cant "replace root" because I nedd theese fields

```
db.getCollection('myColl').aggregate([  { $unwind : "$users" },  {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$users" }}, {$unwind : "$brothers" } ])
```

**EDIT**

Running @Anthony Winzlet query I had this output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "B1",
    "brotherFirstName": "Karl",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastname": "Peters"
  },
  {
    "_id": "B2",
    "brotherFirstName": "May",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Raul",
    "lastname": "Other"
  },
  {
    "_id": "B3",
    "brotherFirstName": "Bryan",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Paul",
    "lastname": "Ray"
  },
  {
    "_id": "B4",
    "brotherFirstName": "Carla",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Anders"
  },
  {
    "_id": "B5",
    "brotherFirstName": "Stuart",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Zoy",
    "lastname": "Bat"
  },
  {
    "_id": "B6",
    "brotherFirstName": "Carter",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Ana",
    "lastname": "Lily"
  }
]
```

The field _id was overwritten by brother's _id field. I need project _id from root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [**`$mergeObjects`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) with the **`$$ROOT`** document. First with the `user` and second with the `brother` and last you have to use [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to remove the `user` and `brother` objects

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$user" },
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$$ROOT", "$user"] }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$brothers" },
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$brothers", "$$ROOT"] }
  }},
  { "$project": { "brothers": 0, "user": 0 }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g1syLuy93Fj)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "brotherFirstName": "Karl",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastname": "Peters"
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "brotherFirstName": "May",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Raul",
    "lastname": "Other"
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "brotherFirstName": "Bryan",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Paul",
    "lastname": "Ray"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "brotherFirstName": "Carla",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Anders"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "brotherFirstName": "Stuart",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Zoy",
    "lastname": "Bat"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "brotherFirstName": "Carter",
    "city": "NY",
    "firstName": "Ana",
    "lastname": "Lily"
  }
]
```

Comment: That's great! But I had a problem. The _id field of the parent element is being overwritten with the value of the child element _id field. Some fields have the same name in the parent element and child element. Is there a way to choose which field I want to keep the value in?

Comment: Ok update your question with the new sample collection and the output. Then I can see it.

Comment: I edited my question. I readed on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/ that mergeobject overwrites same fields name. Can I project or supress thesses fields before mergeObjects?

Comment: @Alberto Updated my answer

Comment: @Alberto Again updated my answer. Keep the `$$ROOT` in the second expression of the `$mergeObjects`